# Listener keeps executing in false if statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I am writing a Chrome extension which has a content script that executes certain actions on `seclectionchange` event, but it is desired for these actions to execute only when the user has enabled them in the extensions settings.

Here is my code:

```js
const readOption = async(key) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result) {
      if (result[key] === undefined) {
        reject();
      } else {
        resolve(result[key]);
      }
    });
  });
};

async function myAsyncFunction() {
  let checkVariable = await readOption('mykey');

  if (checkVariable === true) {

    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(e) {
      // Doing stuff
    }, false);
  }
}

myAsyncFunction();

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, area) => {
  if (area === 'sync' && changes.mykey) {
    myAsyncFunction();
  }
});
```

And here is the problem. When I change the variable from true to false as I can see by setting breakpoints the `if (checkVariable === true)` gets executed triggered by the onChanged listener and then its body gets skipped, because the variable is false.

But after that the `selectionchange` executes as if it is not in the if statement. I have to reload the page to prevent its execution.

How do I solve this issue? I thought of removing the `selectionchange` listener in the `onchanged` listener only when the mykey is set to false, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register an event listener without specifying `{once: true}`, it will be active forever in this page until you unregister it explicitly using removeEventListener with the same function reference. To ensure sameness you can simply move the function to the outer scope where it'll be persistent:

```js
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  let checkVariable = await readOption('mykey');
  let onoff = `${checkVariable ? 'add' : 'remove'}EventListener`;
  document[onoff]('selectionchange', onSelChange);
}

function onSelChange(e) {
  // Doing stuff
}
```

Comment: Should changing `false` to `{once: true}` in the `selectionchange` listener make my code work as is? Because when I try it the `selectionchange` listener never gets its actions executed.

Comment: With `once`  it won't work when the user makes another selection. As for your new problem, I guess you didn't reload both the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab for the web page. The code in the answer is correct and it does the same thing as your current code when the variable is true.

Comment: No, no! Your solution works fine. A million thanks, because I was moving in cycles!
I'm talking about the `{once: true}` statement. Should this make my initial code work without other changes? Because I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: With `once` it won't work when the user makes another selection.

Comment: I get an error with `async function myAsyncFunction()`: Uncaught (in promise) undefined. The browser highlights the last `}`, but I guess that hasn't any special meaning.
The error happens only when I install the add-on for the first time, if I let the default settings, every time I load a page, but if I press save in settings it stops.

I though there is an issue with the initialization of the settings' variable. Following the example of Google's documentation I use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);`. I tried also a listener with `onInstalled`, but no change.

Comment: It's caused by the unnecessary `reject` in your code. You can simplify readOption to `return (await chrome.storage.sync.get(key))[key]`

Comment: But why? Is the key initially undefined? Aren't the default settings stored in place from the first moment of installation?

Comment: No such thing as default settings.

Comment: What do you mean? I initialize the option variables. I even tried with a listener with `onInstalled`. So why are they `undefined`?

Comment: I don't see where you initialize them.

Comment: Please ask a new question.